# Fourier series calculate $f^2$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have the function\fourier series

$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{4} +  \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{3^k}\cos(2kx) $$

and I am asked to compute the integral

$ \int_{0}^\pi f(x)^2 dx$

How do I proceed? I think I should use Parseval's identity, but my attempts failed, and I don't know how the fact that the period is $\pi$ might affect the calculation

Thanks!

Comment: Big hint:  What is $\int_0^{\pi} \cos mx \cos nx dx$ when $m$ and $n$ are different whole numbers?

Comment: Using Werner formula I might be able to comput it but I'm not quite sure how that should be related. I'd get the sum of two sine functions

Comment: OK, let's work this out.  The function is even, so the integral I proposed is $(1/2)\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\cos mx \cos nx) dx$.  And the sine functions in your antiderivative are periodic between these limits ... .

Comment: That would be 0, rigth?

Comment: Bulls eye.  Now put that result into the square of your given sum and note how it simplifies.

Comment: When I square the sum, all the mixed products would become 0 and I'd only have the squared terms, right? Which would then resemble perseval formula with sum of a_n (and b_n) squared.

Comment: Boom!  Got it now?